# Get first word between two symbols and check next word

Tags: jquery

I want to get the first word between two chars "[" and "]".

So

```
func( [test1 param1=john param2=test] )
```

will get "test1".

Now I want to check if the next element after [test1 ...] == [test2], so

```
[test1 param1=john param2=test][test2 param1=john param2=test][/test1] -> true
[test1 param1=john param2=test][test3 param1=john param2=test][/test1] -> false
```

All this with jquery. I hope its clear, what I want to do :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LIVE:](http://jsfiddle.net/b4kkjhvo/)

---

```
var line = [];
line.push( "[test1 param1=john param2=test][test2 param1=john param2=test][/test1]" );
line.push( "[test1 param1=john param2=test][test3 param1=john param2=test][/test1]" );

for (var i=0, l=line.length; i<l; i++) {
    var word1 = line[i].indexOf('[') + 1;
    word1 = line[i].substring(word1, line[i].indexOf(' '));
    var param2 = line[i].substring(line[i].indexOf(']'), line[i].length);
    var word2 = param2.indexOf('[') + 1;
    word2 = param2.substring(word2, param2.indexOf(' '));
    alert(
            word1 + " - " + word2 + " - " + 
            (word1 == 'test1' && word2 == 'test2')
         );
}
```